# What to do with a $ character in variable

Tags: bash, pattern-matching

While searching (& learning) about bash pattern matching, I've discovered that a dollar in variable seems to be interpreted as something else. Referring to the $ after AGENT=

For instance, I'm trying to find the value of 'agent' in:

```
PAGE1="...&METHOD=GET&AGENT=$SM$NpBsRicQN9x%CBn&TARGET=$SM$https%3a%2f%2fwww..."
```

using:

```
if [[ $PAGE1 =~ ^.*AGENT=([\$a-zA-Z]*) ]]
then
    echo ${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
...
```

and the first $ won't be captured. Why?

This is testing now, later to be $PAGE1 from a cURL request.

Comment: And maybe because you are using `AGENT` in the variable but `SMAGENTNAME` in the regexp.

Comment: @rodrigo That's a typo.

Comment: It is recommended that a regexe is put in a variable and to use the variable on the right side of the match operator.

Comment: @DennisWilliamson Very good idea. I'll look into that somme more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is behaving this way because your input `PAGE1` isn't defined correctly.

You have it like this:

```
 PAGE1="...&METHOD=GET&AGENT=$SM$NpBsRicQN9x%CBn&TARGET=$SM$https%3a%2f%2fwww..."
```

You're using *double quotes in your assignment and that is a problem* as this is being interpreted as;

```
PAGE1='...&METHOD=GET&AGENT=%CBn&TARGET=%3a%2f%2fwww...'
```

Since everywhere `$` is appearing shell is trying to expand the following text as shell variables.

**You should use single quotes to avoid shell expansion. This is correct assignement:**

```
PAGE1='...&METHOD=GET&AGENT=$SM$NpBsRicQN9x%CBn&TARGET=$SM$https%3a%2f%2fwww...'
```

Comment: OMG. That was easy. It's time to go back to a bash guide.